# Menu with Appcelerator Titanium and tabgroups

Tags: menu, titanium

I got a problem with creating a menu on a page contains tabs (tabgroups). When i insert the menu's code in a simple window, it works fine. But when i insert the same code on a tabgroup, no menu appears when running. I searched about this problem and it seems that the ancien version of SDK not supported menus on a tabgroups.
anyone can help me about this ?

this is my code:

```
<Alloy>
    <TabGroup id="mainTabGroup">
        <Tab id="tab3" onClick="getTodoList">
            <Window id="readWin">
                <Menu id="menu">
                    <MenuItem id="settingitem" onClick="doAction" title="Settings" showAsAction="Ti.Android.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS">
                    <MenuItem id="calitem" onClick="doAction" title="Calendar" showAsAction="Ti.Android.SHOW_AS_ACTION_NEVER">
                    <MenuItem id="logitem" onClick="doAction" title="Logout" showAsAction="Ti.Android.SHOW_AS_ACTION_NEVER">
                </Menu>
                <TableView id="tableView" onClick="doSomething"/>
            </Window>
        </Tab>
    </TabGroup>
</Alloy>
```

Comment: Please provide some code that shows your menu and how you are adding to the tab group.

Comment: hi Dnevels, this is my code: <Alloy> 
<TabGroup id="mainTabGroup"> 
 <Tab id="tab3" onClick="getTodoList"> 
  <Window id="readWin"> 
      <Menu id="menu"> <MenuItem id="settingitem" onClick="doAction" title="Settings" showAsAction="Ti.Android.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS">
        <MenuItem id="calitem" onClick="doAction" title="Calendar" showAsAction="Ti.Android.SHOW_AS_ACTION_NEVER">
<MenuItem id="logitem" onClick="doAction" title="Logout" showAsAction="Ti.Android.SHOW_AS_ACTION_NEVER"></Menu>
<TableView id="tableView"  onClick="doSomething"/>
 </Window> 
       </Tab> 
     </TabGroup> 
</Alloy>

Answer (score 0):

I think your [showAsAction](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/api/Titanium.Android.MenuItem-property-showAsAction) should be :

```
showAsAction="Ti.Android.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS"
```

Comment: hi, the response is here : http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/175797/problem-with-menu-with-tabgroups#comment-214187